# Certbot failed to authenticate some domains

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-20.04, certbot

This is my first time building a server and hosting it to AWS EC2. When running the command  `sudo certbot certonly --standalone` or `sudo certbot certonly --webroot` I recieved this error below

```
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: standalone). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: matthieuxroger.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: Invalid response from http://matthieuxroger.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/nWRAFCcRUeVxZ0C5YtRg_9bihG2YQeqacUcGjxdCMzg [18.205.22.32]: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <title>Matthieux Roger</title>\n    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />\n "
```

I am using nodejs on ubuntu 20 running on AWS EC2. Any help would be apprieciated.

Comment: can your instance access the internet, you should check your security group? you need to open port 443 and 80 (inbound) you should include the security group configuration in your question also.

Answer (score 9):

When using the `webroot` method with Certbot, a web server is spun up that serves a single file, so that Let's Encrypt can verify the ownership of the server at a domain. But when LE accessed your domain, it got a different server that served a 404 page. It seems that the DNS for your domain isn't pointing to the EC2 instance that is requesting a certificate. (or perhaps it has been updated but just hasn't propagated yet). You need to update the DNS records to point to the server requesting a certificate with certbot. Alternatively, you can use a different challenge type that doesn't require running a server to prove ownership (such as `dns-01`).

Answer (score 2):

check the domain name server in your domain name registration that you have just the A record point to your address and delete other A records